# How to stop event propogation?

Tags: javascript, events, file-upload, attachment, esri

I am using arcgis API's attachment editor

```
var attachmentEditor = new AttachmentEditor({}, dom.byId("content"));
          attachmentEditor.startup();

featureLayer.on("click", function(evt) {
    var objectId = evt.graphic.attributes[featureLayer.objectIdField];
    map.infoWindow.setTitle(objectId);
    attachmentEditor.showAttachments(evt.graphic,featureLayer);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.screenPoint,map.getInfoWindowAnchor(evt.screenPoint));
  });
  map.addLayer(featureLayer);
```

i have written a code on file change button to check for duplicates files

```
$("input[type='file'][name='attachment']").change(function(e){ 

    var file=e.target.files[0];
        for (var a in attachments){
                if (attachments[a].contentType === file.type &&  attachments[a].name === file.name && attachments[a].size === file.size)
                {
                    console.log("duplicate");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }                    
});
```

now i want to stop event propagation to stop so that files doesnt get attached! but the esri onchange event also triggers and the file gets attached. how to stop propogation? so that only my onchange event gets called.

Comment: try to use event.preventDefault();

Comment: @MayankVadiya i used it it but its not working.. see code i have used it

Comment: event.preventDefault() only works if your listener is handled prior to any others. Insure that your handler is being called prior to others. then event.preventDefault() coupled with event.stopImmediatePropagation() should do the trick.

Comment: @Decoded the prior event is esri's api event ...so i cant handle the listner prior to it..

Comment: Also, i'm pretty sure that when the 'change' function is fired, you've already attached the file.... So if you're trying to NOT attach...a different event maybe?

Comment: @Decoded i couldnt find any event 'before attach'